# A continuous bijection from the Cantor Set to [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $C$ is the Cantor Set, I am asked to show that there exists a continuous bijection, say $f$, that maps $C \to [0,1]$.

My best guess thus far has been the Cantor Function, however (using [this construction](http://epicmath.org/2012/11/27/5-the-cantor-set-and-the-cantor-function/)) it doesn't appear to me to be a bijection, specifically not injective. If this is the case, is it possible for me to modify the Cantor Function to get a bijection?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Can't be done. A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. The Cantor set is not homeomorphic to the interval.

Comment: Are you sure you were asked that?

Comment: The question specifically asks to map from $C \to (0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$, but I (after discussing with several classmates) assumed it was a typo. Is this assumption incorrect? Can we map a continuous bijection from the cantor set to (0,1)?

Comment: No, not even a continuous surjection from $C$ to $(0,1)$. A continuous image of a compact space is compact. $C$ is compact, $(0,1)$ is not.

Comment: But the Cantor Function can map the Cantor set onto $[0,1]$ (i.e.: subjective) and is continuous, correct?

Comment: @The Cantor function's domain is $[0,1]$, not $C$.

Comment: Can we not restrict the domain to $C$?

Comment: Yes, there **is** a continuous **surjection** from $C$ to $[0,1].$ But there is **no** continuous **bijection** from $C$ to $[0,1],$ and there is **no** continuous **surjection** from $C$ to $(0,1).$

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll have to have a talk with my professor about this question!

Comment: @Tadpole, yes if you restrict the Cantor function to $C$, it is continuous and surjective there.

http://www.ms.uky.edu/~perry/676/Docs/ps1s.pdf

Answer (score 5):

On the one hand we have

$C=\{ \sum_{k \in N}\frac{a_k}{3^k}$, where $a_k\in \{0,2\} \}$.

On the other hand we have

$[0,1]=\{ \sum_{k \in N}\frac{b_k}{2^k}$  where $b_k \in \{0,1\} \}$.

We put $f(\sum_{k \in N}\frac{a_k}{3^k})=\sum_{k \in N}\frac{c_k}{2^k}$
where $c_k=0$ if $a_k=0$ and $c_k=1$ if $a_k=2$. Then $f$ is a continuous surjection. It is not injective, because $f(\frac{1}3)=f(0.0222...)=\frac{1}{2}=f(0.2)=f(\frac{2}{3})$.

Comment: @XavierYang sorry for rejecting your edit. When reviewing, we don't see comments, so please include in your edit summary that we need to look there to properly understand the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $C$ is compact and $[0,1]$ is separated, any continous bijection $C \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a homeomorphism. However, $C$ and $[0,1]$ are *not* homeomorphic (proof: connectedness).

There are however
 - a continuous injection $C \rightarrow [0,1]$ (this is the standard injection),
 - a continous surjection $C \rightarrow [0,1]$ (this is true even when replacing $[0,1]$ by *any* compact set [(proof)](http://www.mtts.org.in/userapps/download-expo.php?fileid=24); conversely, any continuous image of $C$ is quasi-compact).

Comment: By "any compact set" you mean "any compact metric space", right? Of course there are compact Hausdorff spaces of cardinality greater than the continuum, so those can not be images of $C$.